# How can we increase the number of threads and the complexity of the tests at the same time without needing to fire up parallel JMeter servers

Tags: jmeter

We have a suite a JMeter tests for a SAAS application, we have one master test that imports stand-alone customer specific test. We have one input data file with randomized users for the groups of customers under test and basically a large IF statement that runs that user through a customer specific test.

We are finding that adding more customers (i.e.: more subtests or making the test larger) is consuming ever more memory, at the same time we are trying to add more concurrent threads. The formula seems to be test size * threads, which means any change in the test size is immediately factored into more memory usage.

1. What is the best practice for running JMeter given that we want one test to test multiple customers and we want to add customers (more test complexity) and more concurrency at the same time.
2. Is there a way to structure the tests such that we do not suffer a per-thread memory impact when we add more customers to the test?

Comment: Are you aware that you can use Jmeter in a master-multiple slave mode, so even when you have multiple server, you're controlling the entire test from 1 jmeter instance?

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter threads don't share a lot of resources except maybe startup context. Each additional thread added to the test adds an incremental amount of resource usage. The only way to make the entire test more efficient is to make every thread leaner. Some things to try:

- Use the simplest sampler possible for your application
- If you can use 1 sampler in a loop with variables rather than a bunch of very similar samplers
- Cut down the amount of runtime operations like exractions, assertions, saving responses etc. Use bare minimum
- Make sure there are no GUI based listeners in your test. Response Tree is especially expensive
- Use non-GUI mode `jmeter -n` to launch tests